# Data flow source with wild card chars filename

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to pass dynamic path to data flow source as below.

-->  data/dev/int007/in/src_int007_src_snk_opp_*.tsv

Its not working.

Anyone knows how generate dynamic path with partial filename and wildcard chars ?
I have already tried to use dynamic content options.

[data flow source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoqOl.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZOgA.png)

Answer (score 2):

The container is required and can't be wildcard, you can check if 'data' is your blob container.

in your case:

cantainer:  data

wildcardpath: dev/int007/in/src_int007_src_snk_opp_*.tsv

[image: pic]

Answer (score 1):

'DataFlow expression has error' results when you have invalid syntax for your expression when using dynamic content. In this scenario, I do not think dynamic content is necessary.

As @Atvoid, point your DelimitedText dataset at your blob container 'data' and specify your wildcard path in the dataset source to be 'dev/int007/in/src_int007_src_snk_opp_*.tsv'.

You can verify your wildcard path is working by turning on debug and checking the data preview in your source